# When is index.html generated in Angular build?

Tags: angular, webpack, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to figure out when in the build phase Angular generates the `index.html` file so that I can move it to another directory afterwards. I noticed that when I am trying to copy the files using `WebpackShellPlugin`, `index.html` is not in the dist/projectToMove directory during both `onBuildEnd` and `onBuildExit` phases.

The Webpack config is as follows:

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildEnd: [
        'echo "Files at end of compilation: "',
        'ls ./dist/apps/curemedit/'
      ],
      onBuildExit: [
        'echo "Copying Popup App contents..."',
        'ls ./dist/apps/curemedit/',
        'cp -rvf ./dist/apps/curemedit/* ./dist/apps/'
      ],
      safe: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Output of `ls` for both cases:

```
favicon.ico
main.js
main.js.map
manifest.json
polyfills.js
polyfills.js.map
runtime.js
runtime.js.map
styles.js
styles.js.map
vendor.js
vendor.js.map
```

I have a multi-application Angular workspace for a browser extension. `projectToMove` is the one that will be used for the popup display of this extension. I am trying to move the contents of its corresponding folder in dist one level up so that it is together with the manifest file in the extension's root directory.

My guess was that this delay in generating the `index.html` file is due to ES5 bundle generation for differential loading. I have set 
`Chrome >= 61`
in my `browserslist` file for this project but it turns out that this does not make a difference.

What would be the correct way to grab the index.html file? Should I be watching the folder for longer with a node script or is there a more elegant solution?

**Additional info about my use case:**

I am building a browser extension. Before when it was a single project angular workspace, live reload worked using webpack-extension-reloader as [explained here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575). 
Now that I have two separate angular projects for the popup display and the options page, both of those two project's corresponding index.html pages expect the js and css files in the extension root folder. So now I have an ugly hack using CopyPlugin, WebpackShellPlugin and some sad sed.

Here are the added build config files:

ext.config.js:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: './src/chrome/background.ts'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: './src/chrome/manifest.json',
        to: '../manifest.json'
      }
    ]),
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildExit: [
        // Rename sourcemaps, js and css files -> undo chunks' renamings -> move them to extension root
        'echo "Moving Options App Contents..."',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj1/*.js.map; do mv "$f"  "${f%.js.map}.proj1.js.map"; done ',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj1/*.js; do mv "$f"  "${f%.js}.proj1.js"; done ',
        'mv ./dist/apps/proj1/styles.css ./dist/apps/proj1/styles.proj1.css',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj1/[0-9].proj1.js; do mv "$f" "${f%.proj1.js}.js"; done ',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj1/workspace*.proj1.js; do mv "$f" "${f%.proj1.js}.js"; done ',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj1/workspace*.proj1.js.map; do mv "$f" "${f%.proj1.js.map}.js.map"; done ',
        'mv -v ./dist/apps/proj1/* ./dist/apps/'
      ],
      safe: true
    })
  ]
};
```

ext.popup.js:

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildExit: [
        'echo "Moving Popup App Contents..."',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj2/*.js.map; do mv "$f"  "${f%.js.map}.proj2.js.map"; done ',
        'for f in ./dist/apps/proj2/*.js; do mv "$f"  "${f%.js}.proj2.js"; done ',
        'mv ./dist/apps/proj2/styles.css ./dist/apps/proj2/styles.proj2.css',
        'mv -v ./dist/apps/proj2/* ./dist/apps/'
      ],
      safe: true
    })
  ]
};
```

sed.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i 's/.js/.proj1.js/g' ./dist/apps/proj1/index.html
sed -i 's/styles.css/styles.proj1.css/g' ./dist/apps/proj1/index.html
sed -i 's/.js/.proj2.js/g' ./dist/apps/proj2/index.html
sed -i 's/styles.css/styles.proj2.css/g' ./dist/apps/proj2/index.html
```

package.json:

```
"build": "rm -rf ./dist/ && ng build proj1 && ng build proj2 && ./sed.sh",
"buildprod": "rm -rf ./dist/ && ng build proj1 --prod && ng build proj2 --prod && ./sed.sh"
```

Comment: I've done this with a `postbuild` npm script. So any time i run the `build` command, the `postbuild` will run; which just calls a node script that moves the files

Comment: That does not work for me as I need `ng build project1 --watch` to be running and postbuild scripts give me errors in this case. So I am left with no live reload and debugging.

Comment: whats your use case, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @c_ogoo, I have updated the answer. Mainly it's because I need to be able to have live-reload and be able to test my changes to my extension for a fast enough development pace.

Comment: "I need to *understand the build lifecycle phases..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't fully understand your use case but hopefully this helps.

The Angular CLI allows to configure the `index` property. By default this is only a path which specifies where the `index.html` file is in your src directory. The output path will then be the same as the input path. But the CLI also accepts an object which specifies the input path and the output path.

The property is deeply nested in the `angular.json` file. In a newly generated application it's located at `projects` > `project-name` > `architect` > `build` > `index`.

```
"index": {
    "input": "src/index.html",
    "output": "../index.html"
}
```

This will place the `index.html` file one level above the other files. Unfortunately this will not alter the references to the other files inside the `index.html` file. This still needs to be done outside. I think this is a bug and therefore created a [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16131).

Comment: Thanks for the insight and the bug report. The scenario is that I have two index.html files both of which expect their referenced js/css files in the root folder. These index.html files themselves are in their own proj1 and proj2 subfolders by default but for some reason I don't need to alter the js/css file paths in index.html files to point one level up instead of the same folder. So the bug does not actually affect my use case luckily.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just output the build in the correct folder? Why fight the build if you can just have the output in your preferred target?

Using `@angular/cli` I would just edit the `angular.json` so the `"outputPath"` is not `"dist/appname"` but whatever suits your use case.

Whatever the case, I think the index.html is the single file you really don't need to copy: it's contents never change, at least if you keep the file names consistent, without hash codes.

Why don't you simply keep a precompiled index.html wherever you need it, and simply put your build output in a subfolder?

Comment: 3 reasons: I have two index.html files both of which expect their referenced js/css files in the root folder. Their contents are slightly different depending on whether they are from dev or prod builds. If I put the build files in a subfolder, I would still have to alter the path references in the html files, which gets assumed to be in same directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

All I did to fix it was to

- update firebase.json destination to the correct file path where
  Index.html was.
- rerun the build and
- rerun firebase deploy